# Route 53 + Github Pages -> Custom Domain Published But Site Can't Be Reached

Tags: github, github-pages, amazon-route53

According to every tutorial out there here is my DNS configuration:

[image: DNS victor]

**But** on Github I have:

[image: github vitor]

(My `CNAME` file in my repo contains only one line: `vict0rs.ch`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: DNS propagation. It was all right, just had to wait. Like an hour in my case but I guess it depends on a lot of things.